# Conditional Tag for has post

Tags: posts, get-posts, conditional-tags

I am quite new to all the programming, and I am now stuck with the following.

I installed the plug-in [If Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/faq/) which lets you show specific menu items when Conditional statements are true or false. I want to show a menu item when the logged-in user has made a post, but with a custom post type, called job_listing in my case.

If Menu gives this as an example:

```
    // theme's functions.php or plugin file
add_filter( 'if_menu_conditions', 'my_new_menu_conditions' );

function my_new_menu_conditions( $conditions ) {
  $conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'If single custom-post-type', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function($item) {          // callback - must return TRUE or FALSE
      return is_singular( 'my-custom-post-type' );
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

It's for showing the menu item when a specific post-type is being displayed.
I now changed it to this, but it doens't really work:

```
function my_new_menu_conditions( $conditions ) {
 $conditions[] = array(
    'offset'       => 0,
    'author'       => '$current_user',
    'post_type'    => 'job_listing',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'name'    =>  'If User has Listing', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function( ) {  // callback - must return TRUE or FALSE
      return get_posts( $conditions );
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

The menu item now shows when there is any post on the website. So there are two problems:
- The code still looks for posts and not job_listing
- The statement is still true for all posts, not for the post of the logged in user
I guess the array is not working this way.

Can anyone please help me with this? I am pretty tired of all the trying I did without a good knowledge of what I am exactly doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Thomas - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Questions regarding 3rd-party products are generally considered off-topic for our site and are best addressed in the product's official support channels. Please review what is considered [on-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and "[ask]" in our [help]

Comment: Hi @bosco, thanks for your comment. I get that is the case, but unfortunately there is almost no support for the plug-in. Plus, I thought that because this is Wordpress coding with Wordpress conditionals, that this would be allowed.

I really don't now where to go else.

Comment: This is not even a plugin vs WP issue. it's just that you do not yet know what a closure/callback is and what it's parts mean. You will have to learn PHP or consult someone whom you can pay to do the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the plugin, but it seems unlikely that the `$conditions` array you're adding to should contain any variety of WordPress query arguments. Further, referencing the `$conditions` array within a property that you're setting on that very array won't contain the new data you've added, but rather the array as it existed before your additions (i.e. `get_posts( $conditions )` will not pass all of those query arguments you've added to `get_posts()`). Just leave the keys as the example demonstrated and pass your query arguments to the query instead of trying to push them through the `$conditions` variable:

```
function my_new_menu_conditions( $conditions ) {
  $conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'If User has Listing', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function( ) {        // callback - must return TRUE or FALSE
      $args = array(
        'offset'       => 0,
        'author'       => '$current_user',
        'post_type'    => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'  => 'publish'
      );

      return get_posts( $args );
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

The next problem is that the example code states the `condition` must return `TRUE` or `FALSE` - if you check out the documentation for [the `get_posts()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), it details

> #### Return Value
>
> ---
>
> **(array)**
>
> List of WP_Post objects.

So the plugin expects a boolean (`true`/`false`) value, and by returning the return value of `get_posts()` it instead receives an array (either populated with posts or empty). The plugin may interpret that array as either `true` or `false` depending on how it tests the ["truthiness"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) of the `condition`'s return value. Without digging through plugin code yourself, it's better to be safe and explicitly return a boolean value as the plugin requests.

Here, you wish to return `true` if your query finds any (more than 0) posts, so:

```
function my_new_menu_conditions( $conditions ) {      
  $conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'If User has Listing', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function( ) {        // callback - must return TRUE or FALSE
      $args = array(
        'offset'       => 0,
        'author'       => '$current_user',
        'post_type'    => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'  => 'publish'
      );

      $posts = get_posts( $args );

      return 0 < count( $posts );
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

There are a number of other problems here, though

- PHP will evaluate strings in double-quotes `""` for variable replacement, but treats single-quotes `''` as "string-literals" - this means that your query is literally asking WordPress for posts authored by the user `'$current_user'` rather than the value of the variable `$current_user`. You can fix this by placing the variable name in double quotes, or simply no quotes at all.
- The variable `$current_user` is never declared anywhere in your filter. The code may still work if you've defined it in a higher [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), such as the top of the file in which your function resides. In this instance however, you want to use the [WordPress global variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) `$current_user` - so to make sure that `$current_user` is referencing the right data, you should specify as much at the top of your function by adding `global $current_user;`. This is, however, something of a hack - the preferred method for acquiring the current user is the [`wp_get_current_user()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).
- In fixing the previous issues your query will now throw an error. As noted in [the Codex entry on author query parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters), `'author'` should be an *integer* user ID, while `global $current_user` and the return value of [`wp_get_current_user()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) return a [`WP_User` *object*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User). You can get the ID from a `WP_User` object by reading the ID property, i.e. `$id = $current_user->ID;`, or you can take a shortcut and simply call the [`get_current_user_id()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id).

As a final couple reflections, an `'offset'` of `0` is implied, so that argument can be omitted. And really, you only care if *at least* one post exists that fits your criteria, so we can limit the query to one post by setting `'posts_per_page'` to `1`. If there is no current user (i.e. a guest visitor), there's really no reason to run the query at all - we can do this by checking for a user ID of `0`.

Putting it all together:

```
add_filter( 'if_menu_conditions', 'wpse_223598_add_menu_conditions' );

function wpse_223598_add_menu_conditions( $conditions ) {      
  $conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'If Current User has Authored Listing',
    'condition' =>  function( ) {
      $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

      // If the user's not logged in, they can't have authored a listing
      if( 0 === $current_user_id )
        return false;

      $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'author'         => $current_user_id,
        'post_type'      => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
      );

      $listings = get_posts( $args );

      // Return "there are more than 0 listings"
      return 0 < count( $listings );
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

Comment: +2 if I could http://i.imgur.com/icDAk.gif

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help and explanation. You have no idea how many hours I put into this trying to understand it, and you're giving me vital information I can work with, and even the complete code to use. Thank you so much!

The weird thing though is that the plug-in doesn't work anymore, with or without any code added to it. So I can't say yet if it works completely. I will get back to you in a few days if I have figured out what is wrong.